# how to attach a show method?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Sorry if the title is a little vague, Im currently learning jQuery and would like to fade a content div in and out on hover whilst displaying a read more link when hovered and hiding it when unhovered. I can get the div to fade and the read more link to display although at the moment the read more link is inheriting the opacity of the fade of .25, I understand that I have to add this show method but Im not sure what function or method I have to use.

code is here http://jsfiddle.net/kyllle/a4mPS/

if anyone could explain anything to me that would be great as i would love to fully understand as much as possible.

Answer (score 3):

Since the Read More is inside the `widget` div it will fade with the rest of the widget's contents.  Instead, just put it outside but within the `article`: http://jsfiddle.net/a4mPS/1/

Comment: Yup, this is it. Notice, @kyllle, how you fade the div which translates to fading everything inside the div. If you move the link outside the thing that is fading, you are good to go.

Comment: thanks @mVChr and @JasCav now if I want to work out how to position the read more link based on where the image is how could I do that, im happy to go research if I know what Im looking for?

Comment: I've updated this script: http://jsfiddle.net/a4mPS/5/ just position the new div absolutely and z-index it above and you're all set.

Answer (score 1):

You should put the Read More link in a new div outside of the other div and have it positioned where you want it and modify it's visibility or opacity opposite of the "hover" div.